# ORA 54 resouce busy error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a job running in production which abends randomnly with the error ORA 54. When I checked the code, I could see that the presence of `NOWAIT` is causing the issue. Now I decided to test it and wrote an anonymous block as follows.

```
declare
    cursor c1 is
        select * from table where column_1=2 and column_2=2 and column_3=6
        for update of column_4 nowait;
    record_locked exception;
    pragma exception_init (record_locked, -54);
begin
    begin
        open c1;
    exception
        when record_locked then
            dbms_output.put_line('Faced a locked record. Waiting for 2 minutes..');
            dbms_lock.sleep(120);
            open c1;
    end;
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Exception Occured '||SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
end;
```

I opened one session and ran the below query

```
select * from table
where column_1=2 and column_2=2 and column_3=6
for update of column_4 nowait;
```

I didn't commit or rollback and kept the session open. Now I ran the above anonymous block in another session. After waiting for 2 minutes, it failed with ORA 54 error. So my assumption is correct I believe.

Now the thing is when I ran the entire job code containing the first anonymous block in test environment in the same manner, it waited long for the locked records without abending. When I released the lock by rolling back, it updated the records and completed successfully.

I wish to know why?

Comment: Strange. But I have a question: why are you coding your own wait period when `select ... for update wait 120` would have the same effect with no additional code required?

Comment: Colin : I want to show in the logs that the job faced a locked record and then it waited for 2 minutes and then abending.... But even the original code is workng different ways in production and test.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You get different results from test and production because your table contents are different. Your test table doesn't contain any rows that match the where clause, therefore your sessions don't block each other.

Try adding at least one row to your test table that matches the criterion, and you should get the same results as in production.

Comment: Hi Frank : Thanks for the reply. Actually in my test table I created 20 records which matches the where clause and which are the same in production. One more doubt.. Is the sessions should block each other in order to throw exception or the particular session of nowait getting blocked is suffice for the ORA 54 error.

Comment: @prabhath I don't really understand the second part of your comment - are you asking whether the ORA-00054 is to be expected in your scenario? In my opinion, yes. Also, are you really 100% sure that the environment on test and production is exactly identical? (transaction isolation level etc)

Comment: I am not sure about transaction isolation level. My doubt is like why the same code running in 2 different environments have different behaviours. The code containing NOWAIT is throwing exception in production. But when I locked a few records which satisfy where condition in test environment and run the job, instead of throwing ora 54 error it waited till I release the locks and updated the record. I confirmed the same using logs and no of records updated as well as last updated user of records.